Convert multiple transaction records into a summary of concurrent transactions
I have a SQL Server database with license transactions.  I know when a license was checked out and when it was checked back in.
Example:
DAY     HourOut HourIn  Licenses
4/16/2024   2   5   124
4/16/2024   8   13  28
4/16/2024   9   10  28

What I want to know is how many licenses are concurrently checked out at any one time.  The data above tells me that:

from 2-5 there were 124 licenses checked out
from 6-7 there were 0
from 8-9 there were 28
from 9-10 there were 56
from 11-13 there were 28

How do I get the 4 columns above into a 3-column report like below?
Example:
DAY     HOUR    LICENSES
4/16/2024   2   124
4/16/2024   3   124
4/16/2024   4   124
4/16/2024   5   124
4/16/2024   8   28
4/16/2024   9   56
4/16/2024   10  56
4/16/2024   11  28
4/16/2024   12  28
4/16/2024   13  28

I'm struggling to think of what SQL functions or criteria to use to restructure the data as indicated.

I rolled back your changes - we most definitely do not want images. Formatted text (as I have helped you with) is what we want.

Would you ever have a reporting period that crosses the midnight boundary? e.g.: 4/16/2024   23   2   47

Extending AlwaysLearning's question, the data model you have implies that a license can never be checked out for more than 24 hours (because if that was possible then the schema cannot represent what actually happened). Is it true that a license cannot be checked out for more than 24 hours?

The actual HourOut and HourIn columns are full date/times.  I converted them into day and hour because I'm trying to get the usage into "buckets" for reporting purposes.

You can use the GENERATE_SERIES() function in a CROSS APPLY to expand the HourOut/HourIn range into a series of values (hours). From there you only need to group by day and hour and sum the licenses.
SELECT D.Day, H.value AS Hour, SUM(D.Licenses) AS Licenses
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(D.HourOut, D.HourIn) H
GROUP BY D.Day, H.value
ORDER BY D.Day, H.value

The GENERATE_SERIES() is only available in SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions, you can use any of several alternate techniques for generating a series, including the VALUES technique shown below.
SELECT D.Day, H.Hour, SUM(D.Licenses) AS Licenses
FROM Data D
JOIN (
    VALUES -- Not sure if we nee 0..23 or 1..24, so generate 0..24 to handle either
        (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9),
        (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19),
        (20), (21), (22), (23), (24)
) H(Hour)
    ON H.Hour BETWEEN D.HourOut AND D.HourIn
GROUP BY D.Day, H.Hour
ORDER BY D.Day, H.Hour

Both produce the same results:



Day
Hour
Licenses




2024-04-16
2
124


2024-04-16
3
124


2024-04-16
4
124


2024-04-16
5
124


2024-04-16
8
28


2024-04-16
9
56


2024-04-16
10
56


2024-04-16
11
28


2024-04-16
12
28


2024-04-16
13
28



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Thanks!  This does exactly what I was trying to do.  Now as to whether my approach is the right way or not...that's another topic!  I may have caused myself problems by converting the checkout/checkin timestamps into day and hour buckets.
